# How to set context path for shared folder via my web application in the HTTP protocol

Tags: tomcat, href, server.xml

I have a Web application called Trainings and it has all the trainings as a hyperlink in the JSP page. Whenever i click the link, it should launch the trainings.

The training launch files are available in a share folder.(\share folder\training\country\site\launchfile.html)

I want to set this location from my training page through my Trainings Web application deployed in the tomcat server

http://Trainings:8080/(Share folder launch file)

I am not sure how to do this.. Please help me